# How do I monitor cpu usage for standard/ others apps

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-studio-2.3, android-device-monitor

I am currently monitoring CPU usage for my app using Android cpu Monitor. but however, I would like to monitor CPU usage for other apps like skype, gmail etc. individually and per session of usage. Is there a way I can achieve this with android studio or any other app/tool out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use this Android Monitor tool which helps to monitor real time values of memory , cpu usage and network activity. This can also help whether our application will go on out of memory issues. This is just a good tool for improving the performance of the application.

[image]

Comment: I already do for my apps. My question was, how do I use it for other apps like skype and google maps etc ( which are standard apps) or is there any other tool that will help me monitor cpu usage for specific apps which arent my own

Comment: any idea about my question here? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req ( just probably missing something small, have posted all the details)